# Do underdetermined linear equations Ax = b always have exact solutions

Tags: linear-algebra

A system of underdetermined linear equations $Ax = b$, without other constraints, has infinite number of solutions (say, $\hat{x}$). But, do these solutions (say, the minimum-norm solution) always perfectly suit the equation without error, i.e., $A\hat{x} - b = 0$?

Comment: For the overdetermined case, the least-square solution usually leads to $A \hat{x} - b \neq 0 $

Comment: By "solutions", do you mean that $A\hat x = b$? Which implies $A\hat x-b = 0$?

Comment: Yes. Does it always hold for the infinite number of solutions?

Comment: If any solution $\hat x$ satisfies $A\hat x = b$, then it satisfies $A\hat x - b = 0$. But there are underdetermined systems that have no solution.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. For those underdetermined systems which have solutions $\hat{x}$, do the solutions always satisfy $A\hat{x} = b$? Or, for some cases or some solutions, only $A\hat{x} \approx b$?

Comment: By definition, every solution of $Ax=b$ satisfies $Ax-b=0$. That's what *solution* means.

Comment: $\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}x = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$ has no solutions, of course.

Comment: Thank you. For those underdetermined equations having solutions, are there any cases or solutions only leading to $A \hat{x} \approx b$? As you know, this is often true for some overdetermined equations with least-square solutions.